# How to call a function within setTimeout?

Tags: lightning

I have this code in my lightning component helper where I want to call another method form the same helper.

```
window.setTimeout(
  $A.getCallback(function() {
    for(var key in someFieldsets){ 
      if(someFieldsets[key].fieldAPIName == 'sampleField__c' && !$A.util.isEmpty(someFieldsets[key].fieldValue)) {
        this.secondFunction(component);
      }
    }
  }), 2000
);
```

calling `this.secondFunction(component);` works when it is outside the setTimeout but when inside it, it doesn't perform the secondFunction anymore. what is the other option of calling a function within the helper? why does 'this' doesn't work this time?

Comment: May be your if condition is not making it happen. Comment if condition and try it.

Comment: no, i tried to check through console.log inside the if statement. it returns a value.

Comment: this context will not work in setTimeout. You need to pass that using bind. Check url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback for complete understanding.

Comment: i see... thanks

Answer (score 2):

**this** will not work in setTimeout. You need to pass that using bind. Check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241/pass-correct-this-context-to-settimeout-callback) for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use asynchronous functions `setInterval` and `setTimeout` you need to bind the function passed to those methods to the current context (that is: your component itself).

Your component might be referenced all the time in your code using `this`, especially when accessing and changing its own attributes.

To bind the function to your current context, use `.bind(this)` on the function object. Remember: functions are first-class objects, which means that when you call a function the interpreter will return you a representation of it (an object). And that way you can call the `.bind` method.

So if your function is called `doSomethingInOneSecond`, for example, and you are calling it from a method in your component, you'll use it like this:

```js
method() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Hello one second after!')
    }.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

Note: the new(ish) JS syntax of using arrows `=>` requires you to wrap your function with parenthesis:

```js
setTimeout((() => {
    console.log('Hello one second after!')
}).bind(this), 1000)
```